# .Net 5 - Swagger UI - Required Enum in form requires a change to succeed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Have some weirdness with Swagger UI for a .Net 5 WEB API.

I've got required Enums in an object. Which is displaying and setting correctly. But you cannot execute the endpoint without changing the value in the dropdown.

Is there a way I can make it, that the default set value is a valid value when executing?

Example:

[image: Enum validation failure example]

C#:

```
[Required]
public SizeEnum Size { get; set; }
```

Comment: Try : public SizeEnum Size = Enum.Add_VALUE_Here

Comment: @jdweng, does not make a difference. Since it's a non-nullable property, the default value is always the one with the lowest index.

Comment: You can set to any value you want with the equal sign.

Comment: @jdweng, you're misunderstanding the question.

I can set the value. I want the default value to be a valid value in Swagger when I click execute. I need to change the value from the default selected value to another value and back for it to validate successfully. Which isn't user friendly.

Comment: What is the mapping between the c# enumeration and the swagger values?  I think you may be able to use Enum.Parse but I  need to see the mapping.

Comment: @jdweng The mapping is done via `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`. This property is part of an object. This object is a parameter on the endpoint using `FromFormAttribute`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the following for each `enum`:

```
public class Test
{
    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(SizeEnum.Small)] //Default value must be set using System.ComponentModel, and is required to make this work correctly.
    public SizeEnum Size { get; set; }
}
public enum SizeEnum
{
    Small,
    Large
}
```

Update `Startup.cs` with the following:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebapiProject5", Version = "v1" });
    c.UseInlineDefinitionsForEnums();  //add this...
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! for this answer.
I don't know how many different ways I have tried.
But "c.UseInlineDefinitionsForEnums();" did the job.